# React after refreshing page with param showing blank on production but works fine on local

Tags: reactjs

Anyone got any idea why is this happening on my local there is no errors everything compiles fine but on production it's just blank (screenshot)?

[image]

Comment: Which babel presets are you using? Are you exporting from Webpack in production mode?

Comment: "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "babel-eslint": "7" and using docker to build in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the build `index.html` need to add `<base href="/" />`